# Why am I getting a 500 error with these RewriteRules after updating to apache 2.4

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

my rewriterules lines were working fine on apache 2.2.  Last night, after updating to apache 2.4 (with WHM easyapache 3)，the web site with this .htaccess gets 500 error.

Any suggestion please...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^add-p$ index_adp.php
RewriteRule ^Reservations$ Reservations_.php
RewriteRule ^Flight$ Flight.php
RewriteRule ^search$ search.php
RewriteRule ^search_IE$ search_IE.php
RewriteRule share_search$ share_search.php
RewriteRule ^Map-Travel-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ Map_T.php?L1=$1
RewriteRule ^Map-Travel-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+);([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ Map_T.php?L1=$1&L2=$2
RewriteRule ^Map-Travel-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+);([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+);([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ Map_T.php?L1=$1&L2=$2&L3=$3
RewriteRule ^Map-Travel-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+);([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+);([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+);([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ Map_T.php?L1=$1&L2=$2&L3=$3&L4=$4
RewriteRule ^share-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*).html$ share_data.php?sid=$1
RewriteRule ^share-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ share_data.php?sid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ search_data.php?acpid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*).html$ search_data.php?pid=$1&cont=nn&lname=$2&pname=$3&ename=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ search_data.php?pid=$1
```

Comment: What do your logs show? If you don't have access to your logs try simplifying the code until you stop getting the 500 then tell us what produces the 500. Nothing jumps out at me but I also didn't go through every character of the +10 rules.

Comment: Hi, deleting this .htaccess file can also remove 500 error, so I am pretty sure it is the problem . but the very same file works fine in apache 2.2. .....

Comment: If it is just `RewriteEngine On` is the error thrown? Do the first 5 lines throw it, etc. the simplest version will help us help you.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion. I will try it thanks.

Comment: really tested this ruleset with no errors at Apache2.4